# Flash bank swapping with BFB2 on STM32G4

Tags: stm32

I am implementing an OTA update system for the STM32G4, and want to use the dual flash banks to make it safe. That is, write the new firmware in the inactive flash bank while the main program is still running from the active bank, and reboot only after checking the integrity of the newly installed firmware.

To do this, I'm setting the `BFB2` bit from the option bytes to 1, which, according to [AN2606 (section 45.2)](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00167594-stm32-microcontroller-system-memory-boot-mode-stmicroelectronics.pdf) and [this presentation (page 8)](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/training/technical/product_training/08/4c/83/1b/56/bd/45/34/STM32L4_System_SYSCFG.pdf/files/STM32L4_System_SYSCFG.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.STM32L4_System_SYSCFG.pdf), tells the MCU to first attempt booting from flash bank 2 if the stack address located at offset 0x0 of the flash bank 2 is a valid SRAM address. Otherwise the MCU boots from flash bank 1. This fits my use case, as I can write the new firmware to the flash bank 2, except for the stack address which is written only after an integrity check to commit the change.

However, it seems the flash banks addresses aren't swapped when booting from the flash bank 2. According to the [programming manual (section 10.2.1)](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0440-stm32g4-series-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf), swapping the flash banks addresses is done by setting the `FB_MODE` bit, which is cleared on reset and does not seem to be set when booting from flash bank 2. Not having the flash banks addresses swapped automatically is problematic because it means the firmware cannot be linked assuming a flash address of 0x08000000.

The workaround I can think of is to integrate a bootloader that checks which bank is in use, set the `FB_MODE` bit accordingly, then jump to the actual firmware entry point. This bootloader would be flashed in both banks, and not updated during an OTA update.

Is there really no way to swap flash banks addresses automatically when booting from flash bank 2? Or is there another solution which wouldn't involve a bootloader?

Edit: after reading [this thread](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000A7W1CP/bfb2-bit-setreset-effect-takes-place-only-at-power-cycle-boothard-reset) on the ST forums, I am not sure anymore my understanding is correct. If this user is right, then setting `BFB2` swaps the banks and their addresses, and setting `FB_MODE` on top of that would "cancel" the swap.

Answer (score 4):

I finally got this to work after a lot of trial and error. Some of my assumptions were wrong. Here's what the update process looks like:

1. Check the `FB_MODE` bit to know which bank the firmware is currently running from.
2. Perform a mass erase on the other bank (`MER2` bit if `FB_MODE` is 0, `MER1` otherwise).
3. Write the new firmware version at 0x08040000. The inactive bank is always mapped at that address, regardless of `FB_MODE`.
4. Set the `BFB2` bit in the option bytes if `FB_MODE` is 0, or clear it otherwise. Do not blindly toggle `BFB2`, because it does not necessarily reflect which bank is active.
5. Reload option bytes with the `LAUNCH` bit, which also resets the MCU.
6. If the stack top address written at 0x08040000 is valid, the ST bootloader should boot to the new firmware. See step 1.

Some notes:

- The firmware is always linked with a virtual address of 0x08000000, regardless of which bank it will be flashed to.
- In dual bank mode, the main flash is NOT aliased to 0x0, so the firmware can't be linked to that address.
- This does not update the flash option bytes, only the firmware code. I solved this by updating the flash option bytes if necessary when the new firmware boots for the first time.

Comment: I'm tearing my hair out on this same mechanism.  In my case, after B2BF is set, application code runs for a very short time and then the core resets for no clear reason.  This happens endlessly until I use a programmer tool to flip the BFB2 bit back to 0.  The images in B1 and B2 are bit-for-bit identical.  Do you have any example code from when you got this to work?  See https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00001uyrJNSAY/why-might-setting-bfb2-cause-printf-to-stop-working (the subject is based on an earlier red herring)

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "This does not update the flash option bytes, only the firmware code. I solved this by updating the flash option bytes if necessary when the new firmware boots for the first time."?

Comment: "application code runs for a very short time and then the core resets for no clear reason": that sounds like a watchdog timeout. My last point was that, if the new firmware requires different options bytes, then (obviously) writing the new firmware at 0x08040000 won't do it for you and you will need to update them separately. In my case, the new firmware will do it on the first boot, but you could also do it from the old firmware if you know in advance what the new option bytes must be. (careful not to touch the BFB2 bit in either case though).

Comment: Ah, got it.  In my case the answer turned out to be I was neglecting to assign VTOR.  It defaults to 0x00000000, which works fine if BFB2 isn't set because it maps into flash, but if BFB2 is set, that address maps into system memory.  So as soon as an interrupt came along, execution would pass into the system memory area.  There's one sentence in the app note that explains this. :facepalm: